# how to use sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

It's my first time working with python sockets. I'm making a snake game, to be used on LAN PCs. Python uses a **while** to connect and send information in a client - server.  
 
I need to know how much information, I can send simultaneously, without affecting the speed of the game. I have an array of 4000 records, which correspond to the coordinates of the game. Do I need to do an Algorithm to minimize the transport or not?, how? ... Suggestions, ideas ...   
Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket in Python is defined from a BSD interface. You can start from [socket manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). Server and client is make in similar way as in C.